# POSTGRES date_trunc and Between condition with HOURS and TIMESTAMPS

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

How do you select a value based on truncated hour with the between condition?

In theory, this is what I want to do:

```
select * from table 
where date_trunc('hour', column1) BETWEEN '8:00' and '10:00'
```

I suspect it might be because (a) I am comparing a timestamp to hours and (b) I am not defining my hours correctly.

How do I fix this?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `extract()` or something similar:

```
select *
from table 
where extract(hour from column1) in (8, 9)
```

Or conversion to `time`:

```
where cast(column1 as time) >= '8:00' and
      column1::time < '10:00'
```

Note:  This shows two methods of doing the conversion, the first is the standard method.  The second is more concise, but Postgres-specific.  Also, I'm leaving out `'10:00'`.  That is easy enough to add back in.